# Font Awesome Icon not appearing

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Having some difficulties with Font Awesome and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction? This is what I have

```
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sectionTitle">
      <div class="section colour1">
        <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x">Camera 3px</i>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When the page is then rendered however the camera icon is not appearing, although the Camera 3px text is. I'm sure I've overlooked something fundamental here. Any thoughts at all on this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You have to add all files of font-awesome library properly.

Comment: It's working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Y5GUA/. Are you running the development machine offline ?

Comment: Consider moving the `Camera 3px` text outside of the `i` tag: `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> Camera 3px`

Comment: This showed up in related questions... if you're still looking for the solution see this answer I just wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812241/font-awesome-not-appearing-in-the-browser

Answer (score 1):

It is loading here:

```
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"     rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sectionTitle">
      <div class="section colour1">
        <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x">Camera 3px</i>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CLVx4/

Guess you did it all correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I agree this is not an answer, so why was my flag disputed?

Comment: @Andy I have no idea, I am not a moderator. I came across this question in a review queue, so the comment was provided on my behalf automatically.

Comment: Probably because he has not enough reputation to add a comment

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct so I think the problem is elsewhere.

If you are viewing the page through `file://` URI scheme, rather than `http://`, the link to the external CSS file will not work without specifying `http://` explicitly in the link url, this has caught me out plenty of times. May be worth changing the link to:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```